# IBM watson diarization

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, watson

Hello I'm developing an application with c# visual studio 2017, I test the code for speech to text and its working but now I need to do speaker diarization

How can I do that?

```
SpeechToTextService _speechToText = new SpeechToTextService();
_speechToText.SetCredential("", "");
//var results = _speechToText.GetModels();
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("mp3"))
{  
    //  get a transcript of the audio file.
    var results = _speechToText.Recognize("audio/mp3", fs);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out the solution

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/05/whos-speaking-speaker-diarization-watson-speech-text-api/

the code looks like this:

```
var results = _speechToText.Recognize("audio/mp3", fs,null, "en-US_BroadbandModel", null, true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,false, true, **true**);
```

the last `true` identifies the `speaker_label`, the results will be in this way.

https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/speech-to-text/output.html#output